# Multiple timeouts in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, timeout

I have several objects I need to maintain with time-to-live parameters, and trigger some kind of event when they time out.

Implementing this as a timer that just waits for a the object with the smallest TTL before popping it off a queue doesn't seem very efficient because I need to be able to add/remove objects sporadically from this queue (and they can have any time out value), possibly before they time out. For example, ugly things would happen if I think that the shortest TTL object is 10 seconds and block the timeout thread for 10 seconds, but during this period an object with 3 seconds to live is added to the queue.

The naive way of doing

```
while (true) {
 update()
}

void update() {
 // get delta since last call to update()
 // subtract delta from each object and time out if ttl < 0
}
```

is pretty slow since there is a lot of memory being shuffled around for the sole purpose of updating ttl on microsecond resolution.

Is there a good way to do this without creating a separate thread for each object?

I have access to the C++11 std lib but no boost or any external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

One *easy* but somewhat crappy option is to poll for updates to the queue - say every second or tenth of a second.  Too often and your OS may not have time to yield for some productive work; too infrequently and your timing capability becomes very crude.  You can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(n))` for the inter-poll delay, or may want to use e.g. `select` if you are doing other I/O too.  You can have any accesses to the queue arbitrated by a mutex, and use say a `std::map<std::chrono::time_point, Task>` to keep `Tasks` sorted by TTL, so each time the poll period expires you just iterate from `.begin()` towards `.end()`, exiting early if the `time_point` has not elapsed yet.

> ...without creating a separate thread for each object?

The above can be done is a single background thread if desired.

Another option: a non-Standard OS-provided asynchronous notification mechanism such as a signal-raising alarm... e.g. [`alarm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?alarm+2), but your signal is typically only allowed to do a fairly restricted number of operations though, the normal advice is to set a flag so the interrupted thread can know there's work for it to do - that's not much different to having to check the queue for expired `Tasks` anyway, but the advantage is the signal itself can force some blocking operations to terminate early (e.g. without `SA_RESTART` flag to `sigaction`), with error codes indicating the reason for the interruption.  Decades ago I came across some blocking operations on some Operating Systems that had limited guarantees about the state of I/O buffers the interrupted routine may have been using, making it impossible to build a robust resumption of that I/O - check your OS docs.